# Pickling a httplib.HTTPMessage fails <1% of the time for URLs with spaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, httplib

In Python 2.7.2 pickling a `httplib.HTTPMessage`  works literally more than 99% of the times. But sometimes on rare occasions, it fails:

```
dumps(info)

TypeError: can't pickle StringO objects


dumps(info, 2)

PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'cStringIO.StringO'>: attribute lookup cStringIO.StringO failed
```

How can I find out what member of the `httplib.HTTPMessage` class (which `info` is an instance of) has the problem?

I got `info` from calling `open()` on an object returned from  `urllib2.build_opener`. All URLs which have failed so far have spaces in them.

Comment: So you're saying that if you take a single object and pickle it 100 times in a row, 1 of those times it will fail to pickle?

Comment: Gabe: No, I am pickling different objects obtained by downloading different URLs. Most of the time it works.

Comment: So then is it certain URLs that don't work while others always do?

Comment: Can you post a URL that fails?